# Where to find fossil databases

Tags: database

Looking for sites with fossil data in the following categories.

- Fossil cells
- Fossil invertibrates
- Fossil fish
- Fossil amphibians
- Fossil reptiles
- Fossil dinosaurs
- Fossil birds
- Fossil mammals
- Fossil insects
- Fossil plants
- Fossil mushrooms
- Fossil humans

I would like for the sites to be copyleft (i.e. free, public domain, or creative commons type license) if possible, not necessary though. However, some museums such as [the British museum](http://www.britishmuseum.org/about_this_site/terms_of_use/copyright_and_permissions.aspx) are copyleft. Also, many other sites that google brings up are not working.

The sites I have found are mostly not copyleft:

1. [American Museum of Natural History - Paleontology](https://www.amnh.org/our-research/paleontology/collections) (4.75 million specimens) (very restrictive, only personal/educational use)
2. [Paleoportal](http://paleoportal.org/index.php?globalnav=footer_pages&sectionnav=about) (aggregated stuff from the University of California Museum of Paleontology, the Paleontological Society, the Society of Vertebrate Paleontology, and the United States Geological Survey). This may touch on all of the fossil categories above.
3. [Paleobiodb](https://paleobiodb.org/navigator/). (top categories: Mollusca, Brachiopoda, Arthropoda, Mammalia, Cnidaria, Radiolaria)
4. [Fossil works](http://fossilworks.org/)
5. [Florida Museum - Natural History Collections](https://www.floridamuseum.ufl.edu/collections/databases/) ([botany](https://www.floridamuseum.ufl.edu/herbarium/cat/), plus others)
6. [Bryophyportal](http://bryophyteportal.org/portal/misc/usagepolicy.php). Unfortunately, the images are only for personal/educational use. Looking for sites that allow free use of the content (such as copyleft licences like creative commons, or as public domain).
7. [UCMP](https://ucmpdb.berkeley.edu/disclaimer.shtml) (not copyleft, personal/educational use only)

Wondering if these are good enough, or if there is anything else that should be added to this list to cover the categories above.

Comment: No such database exists, you have already found the best that is available. there is a current effort to build one, but these are disconnected, poorly funded and in some cases dead( poor dinosauricon). Sadly wikipedia is currently one of the better websites for finding such things. Part of the issue is for many of those categories there are only a handful of scientists even studying it.